Show that there are infinitely many composite integers $n$ such that $n \mid (3^{n - 1} - 2^{n - 1})$
Problem: Show that there are infinitely many composite integers $n$ such that $n \;|\; (3^{n - 1} - 2^{n - 1})$.
My Solution: Suppose that $n$ is the product of two distinct primes $n := pq$. Then, by Fermat's Little Theorem, $n \mid 3^{n - 1} - 2^{n - 1}$ is equivalent to
$$q \mid 3^{p - 1} - 2^{p - 1} \quad \text{and} \quad p \mid 3^{q - 1} - 2^{q - 1}.$$
First, we claim that if $p \equiv 1, 5, 19, 23 \pmod{24}$, then $p$ is not a primitive divisor of $3^{p - 1} - 2^{p - 1}$ (i.e. $p$ divides $3^x - 2^x$ for some $x < p - 1$ as well as $x = p - 1$). Indeed, if $p \equiv 1, 5, 19, 23 \pmod{24}$, then $\bigl(\tfrac{6}{p}\bigr) = 1$, using the Legendre symbol. By Euler's Criterion, $$6^{\tfrac{p - 1}{2}} \equiv \left(\frac{6}{p}\right) \equiv 1 \equiv 4^{\tfrac{p - 1}{2}} \pmod{p}.$$  By dividing both sides by $2^{\tfrac{p - 1}{2}}$, we get that $p \mid 3^{\tfrac{p - 1}{2}} - 2^{\tfrac{p - 1}{2}}$.
The infinitude of primes of that form is given by Dirichlet's Theorem. Returning to the original problem, fix $p \ge 7$ to be some prime congruent to $1$, $5$, $19$, or $23$ modulo $24$. By Zsigmondy's Theorem, there exists a primitive divisor of $3^{p - 1} - 2^{p - 1}$, which is distinct from $p$. Let it be $q$. Then, by minimality $\operatorname{ord}_q \bigl(\tfrac{3}{2}\bigr) = p - 1$. Since we know that $q \mid 3^{q - 1} - 2^{q - 1}$ by Fermat's Little Theorem, $p - 1 \mid q - 1$. This implies that $p \mid 3^{q - 1} - 2^{q - 1}$. So, we are done.
Questions:

I believe that this proof is correct. However there are some things that I don’t like about it. Is there no easier way to prove that: There are infinitely many primes $p$ such that $p$ is not the only primitive divisor of $3^{p - 1} - 2^{p - 1}$? My proof of this fact is rather long, relies on the reader being able to calculate $\bigl(\frac{6}{p}\bigr)$ using Gauss’s Lemma and the Quadratic Reciprocity, and I think it distracts from the overall motivation of the proof which is just Zsigmondy’s Theorem; everything else is just patching up the small holes. Also, I don’t particularly like how this proof relies on Dirichlet’s Theorem, as it is quite difficult to prove, although the special case of $p \equiv 1 \pmod{n}$ is easier, using only cyclotomic polyonomials.
Is there a completely different approach to the entire problem? Setting $n = pq$ was the only thing that came to me, however it also restricted the number of possibilities by quite a bit.


Don't think it's easier, but any Carmichael number prime to $6$ works, and there are infinitely many of those (not an easy result).

Nice question (+1).  Quick search doesn't  appear to help much, examples are not exactly common.

@lulu FYI, using an Approach0 search, I also didn't find much here, with just only a couple of questions, one which is the same (i.e., Prove that for infinitely many composite natural numbers n , $n|3^{n-1}-2^{n-1}$, but it doesn't have any answers) and another one which is closely related. However, there are quite a few AoPS threads asking about this problem, with the details about this given in the next comment.

Note the AoPS threads I mentioned in my comment above are Olympiad number theory problem, Infinite composite, NT problems (note it's problem #$2$ there), Show that infinitely many n divides 3^{n-1}-2^{n-1}, $n|3^{n-1}-2^{n-1}$ and  ...

Does this answer your question?

(cont.) Hard number theory.. With the first one I referenced, it states the oldest known source is Moscow MO $1995/11.6$. Also, it gives a solution in Post #$6$ of choosing $n=3^{2^t}-2^{2^t}$. Note that If $n=3^{2^k}-2^{2^k}$, then $n\mid 3^{n-1}-2^{n-1}$ here has a couple of answers showing this.

Note with $k \gt 0$ that $3^{2^k}-2^{2^k}=\left(3^{2^{k-1}}-2^{2^{k-1}}\right)\left(3^{2^{k-1}}+2^{2^{k-1}}\right)$, with both factors $\gt 1$ for $k \gt 1$.

@JohnOmielan  Beautiful, thanks!  I suggest posting that as an answer.  Your call, of course.

@lulu You're welcome. Regarding your suggestion, note what I wrote only addresses the OP's second question, and also the other question I reference of If $n=3^{2^k}-2^{2^k}$, then $n\mid 3^{n-1}-2^{n-1}$ may be considered to be a duplicate instead. Regarding the OP's first question, I don't offhand have any particularly good response to it.

@JohnOmielan  Yeah, but it's such a solid response to the underlying question.  And a really good object lesson for people who leap to the atom bomb vs mosquito solution (as in my Carmichael number remark).

There are infinitely many composite Carmichael numbers. For any Carmichael number, $a^{n-1}\equiv 1 \bmod n$. Hence, for the infinitely many Carmichael numbers, $3^{n-1}-2^{n-1}\equiv 1-1=0 \bmod n$, establishing $n\mid 3^{n-1}-2^{n-1}$
Added in response to comments: This validity of this answer depends on the highly likely, but not demonstrated (to my knowledge), premise that there are infinitely many Carmichael numbers coprime to $6$. After I posted this answer, it was pointed out to me that it substantially the same as a comment by lulu.

$a^{n-1}\equiv 1 \bmod n;$ if $\gcd(a,n)=1$

This answer repeats what was already said yesterday in comments by other users. It is common courtesy to state that in the answer (some users even make the answer CW in such cases).

@Bill Dubuque I honestly missed lulu's comment. Is there any way I can delete my answer now that it has received an upvote?

@Bill Dubuque Apologies, but I do not recognize the abbreviation 'CW'. I have credited lulu's comment.
